# Split bootstrap form from results

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a simple web app using Bootstrap that takes a user's input on a form, send it to a database and then returns the data in a table below the form.  The issue I'm having is more-so on the styling side.  My goal is to have the 2 areas separated *(see image for current setup and desired output)*.

I've researched solutions both on stack overflow and elsewhere and have tried those solutions but so far to no avail.  I'm hoping that what I'm doing wrong is a simple thing (and I kind of feel like it is) and the solution is a very easy fix but I'm not sure.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1 class="headline">Text Items</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <form onsubmit="postText()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputText">Text</label>
              <span><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputText" id="inputText" placeholder="Enter Text ...">
            </div>
  
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputDate">Date</label>
              <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inputDate" id="inputDate">
            </div>
  
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submission">Submit <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary invisible" id="update">Update <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary invisible" id="clearUpdate" onclick="clearUpdateFields()">Clear <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </form>
        
        <br>
        <div id="nothingExists"></div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getTexts()">Get List <span><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></span></button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
          <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <th class="mySortable" onclick="sortTable(0)">Item</th>
              <th class="mySortable" onclick="sortTable(1)">Date</th>
              <th>Options</th>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*(I opted to leave out the default bootstrap script/css calls just because I feel it can get a bit messy)*

I've tried wrapping the form in its own `<div>` and then the `nothingExists` `<div>` and the data table in their own separate second `<div>` but also that didn't work.  On top of that, when the table gets filled with the data, the white background stretches with the table (so ideally the second `<div>` would stretch with the data/would become a scrollable table).

Here's the CSS I've currently got setup:

```
html {
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 600px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #FFFFFF, #1C3F80);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}
body {
    width: 850px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.container {
    width: 850px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    align-items: center;
}


form {
    margin: 0px 10px 20px 10px;
}

.main {
    padding: 20px;
}

th {
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    background-color: white;
}

.mySortable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is the goal:

[image: Goal]

This is the current page:
[image: Current]

I'm not sure how to split them into 2 separate `div`s.  Like I said earlier, hopefully the solution is pretty simple.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make form and table containers siblings with white background, and then use margin to distance them, and padding to arrange elements within, utilizing bootstrap's helpers (m-, p-) or adding your own

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="container bg-info">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1 class="headline">Text Items</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="main">

    <form onsubmit="postText()" class="bg-white mb-5 p-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputText">Text</label>
        <span><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputText" id="inputText" placeholder="Enter Text ...">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputDate">Date</label>
        <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inputDate" id="inputDate">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submission">Submit <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary invisible" id="update">Update <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary invisible" id="clearUpdate" onclick="clearUpdateFields()">Clear <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </form>




    <div id="nothingExists" class="bg-white p-3">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getTexts()">Get List <span><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></span></button>
      <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="mySortable" onclick="sortTable(0)">Item</th>
            <th class="mySortable" onclick="sortTable(1)">Date</th>
            <th>Options</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```